# PHP script won't run in the background

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface

I am trying to run a php CLI script in the background and it just won't run - it has a status of Stopped SIGTOU (Trying to write output) - Here are the details

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2
- PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  8 2011 19:34:00)

I created a basic script  test.php

```
<?php echo 'Hello world'.PHP_EOL; ?>
```

Here are the results of various tests:-

- `php -f test.php`  (Hello world gets displayed)
- `php -f test.php >test.log 2>&1` (Hello world gets put into test.log)
- `php -f test.php >test.log 2>&1 &` --- I get `[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTOU)        php -f test.php > test.log 2>&1` -- and the job just sits there doing nothing nothing gets logged however lsof shows the log file is open

It is something to do with PHP?  A similar shell script gets executed no problems in the background.

Comment: [SIGTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTOU)

Answer (score 5):

If readline is enabled in your build of php, simply pass /dev/null as the input.

In your example above, it would be:

```
php -f test.php </dev/null >test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Good tip! Unfortunately I cannot test it as I have rebuilt PHP without readline support now .... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved now -- thanks to all who responded. The problem was that Apple provide PHP pre-built with the OS - the CLI version was built with readline included - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.readline.php ... this prevents any background running of scripts because readline automatically starts IO with the TTY ...

My problem was that I couldn't build my own version of PHP because of this -> http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1284479 - once I got that resolved my background script issue was gone :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, a PHP script stops when its done execution, ie a simple echo "Hello World" is done execution as soon as it outputted the string, i would guess it have something to do with it ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't explain the SIGTTOU though (background process attempts to write to TTY output).